# Bluebird promisify and callback with no error argument

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to promisify a 3rd party library that doesn't use the `callback(err, data)` pattern. Instead they always return `callback(data)` and `throw` on errors.

```
Promise.promisifyAll(horse);

var p = Promise.defer();
horse.drinkAsync()
    .error(function(data)
    {
        p.fulfill(data);
    })
    .catch(function (err)
    {
        console.error('error occured', err);
    });

return p.promise;
```

What is a nice way to wrap such a behavior with promises and still have it look ok and allow to catch the thrown error? The catch clause doesn't trigger and the application crashes.

Comment: They `throw` on errors?!? What library? Do they always throw synchronously?

Comment: Mind the deferred anti-pattern, you can just `return horse.drinkAsync()` Another anti pattern is catching errors just to log them, that means you don't know how to handle them in this code which means you should just let it bubble until it reaches a layer where you know what to do with it (print "something went wrong" for the user or such). Even if you don't want to inform the user, logging manually is still useless because unhandled errors are logged automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Bluebird 2.1 on, you can now customize `promisifyAll` with a custom promisification handler:

```
function noErrPromisifier(originalMethod){
    return function promisified() {
         var args = [].slice.call(arguments); // might want to use smarter
         var self = this                      // promisification if performance critical
         return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
             args.push(resolve); 
             originalMethod.apply(self,args); // call with arguments
         });
    };
}

var horse = Promise.promisifyAll(require("horse"), {
    promisifier: noErrPromisifier
});

horse.drinkAsync().then(function(data){
     // Can use here, ow promisified normally.
});
```

If the original method throws asynchronously, there is really no way around wrapping it in a domain, although I've never seen a library that acts *that* poorly.

Comment: There's a syntax error in that noErrPromsifier function.