# Bluebird spread returns undefined over ping module

Tags: node.js, promise, ping, bluebird

I have following test code;

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var ping = require('ping');
Promise.promisifyAll(ping);

Promise.some([
    ping.sys.probe("google.com"),
    ping.sys.probe("yahoo.com"),
    ping.sys.probe("microsoft.com"),
    ping.sys.probe("facebook.com")
], 2).spread(function (first, second) {
    debugger;
    console.log(first, second);
}).catch(Promise.AggregateError, function (err) {
    err.forEach(function (e) {
        console.error(e.stack);
    });
}).error(function(err){
    console.log("error: " + err);
});

//    ping.sys.probe("google.com", function(isAlive){
//         var msg = isAlive ? 'host ' + "google.com" + ' is alive' : 'host ' + "google.com" + ' is dead';
//         console.log(msg);
//     });
```

for some reason, function goes into spread handler but both values are undefined.
[ping module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping) is naturally supporting promises and **promisifyAll** might be unnecessary over there.

What would be missing in my implementation?

Comment: Does it propagate to your error handler? The promisify expects a node `err, result` callback, whereas the `probe` method only returns one argument. You may need to create a custom function instead of promisify or use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194808/bluebird-promisify-and-callback-with-no-error-argument).

Comment: Actually, after looking into the library you can use `ping.promise.probe('site')`

Comment: @BenFortune ah, I missed that point! Thanks for noticing and after I used that, it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the promise methods instead, which are at `ping.promise`. The library doesn't need promisifying so you can take that out.

```
Promise.some([
    ping.promise.probe("google.com"),
    ping.promise.probe("yahoo.com"),
    ping.promise.probe("microsoft.com"),
    ping.promise.probe("facebook.com")
], 2).spread(function (first, second) {
    debugger;
    console.log(first, second);
}).catch(Promise.AggregateError, function (err) {
    err.forEach(function (e) {
        console.error(e.stack);
    });
}).error(function(err){
    console.log("error: " + err);
});
```